# Register output glitches and memory writes

Tags: computer-architecture, digital-circuits

When changing the write enable signal, of a memory element, from 1 to 0, what effect does the pipeline's register's output glitch have? Glitch that all of digital logic has, for the time of propagation delay $t_{pd}$. Won't it cause an unnecessary write?

Comment: Is this translated from some less popular language to English by machines without helpful human care? It might be better if you can post the original problem in its original language so that some user here will be able to translate it better.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Hope it's a bit clearer now.